# Algorithm for 'shortest path' with walking agent

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

I am looking for a shortest path algorithm where the agent (the thing that has to move from start to finish) has only a limited view on the walkable field. Let's say we have a labyrinth with a start and a goal that is tile-based. Something like this:
[image]
The agent then might **only be able to see one in each direction (up, down, left, right)** but has **unlimited memory**. As a measurement I want **as few steps as possible** to reach the goal. 
Is there an algorithm for that?

And if so is there an algorithm for a more general problem. Let's say: a graph, multiple goals and starts and a function that returns seen nodes, and limited memory?

A solution using a star with total vision:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while, some ideas and similarities came to my mind.

It is close to the problem that a [Micromouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micromouse) has to solve most use [Flood Fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)

```
Flood-fill (node, target-color, replacement-color):
 1. If target-color is equal to replacement-color, return.
 2. ElseIf the color of node is not equal to target-color, return.
 3. Else Set the color of node to replacement-color.
 4. Perform Flood-fill (one step to the south of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the north of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the west of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the east of node, target-color, replacement-color).
 5. Return.
```

Answer (score 2):

A very simple alternative approach is:

```
walk to an undiscovered tile using a star
if it is the goal stop
if not repeat
if there aren't any undiscovered tiles stop and fail
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically A* will still work but you need to find a new heuristic, i recommend that you include travel time between tiles to do so.

Comment: You should explain your answer in more detail, because it's not clear how someone reading this answer will know how to apply it to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

With limited visibility, you can't really expect to find a shortest path because either you can see a path to the goal or you can't, unless you're lucky enough to see multiple paths.

However, you could use a heuristic to improve your search. For example, you'll want to explore unexplored tiles, prioritizing those around your goal, starting with those that are closest. With visibility of only 1, you're basically blind, but if you had slightly higher visibility, you could prioritize exploring around the goal until you find a path that connects to something you've already explored.

This reminds me of bidirectional path tracing, a technique in rendering where you trace paths from both the camera and the light until they connect. http://www.pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/Light_Transport_III_Bidirectional_Methods/Bidirectional_Path_Tracing.html

Comment: Certainly, you can find the shortest path, as I have shown. But you can not find the minimal steps, yes, at least not in general. Still we could use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation O Notation to see wich algorithm performed better.  Also, I think what you suggested basically is A-Star? I think this does help, but It doesn't solve the problem that you have to calculate how many steps are needed. Last to your link: maybe I missed something but isn't it about a Bidirectional Swarm Algorithm? I do not see how that helps here?

Comment: You can't know you have the shortest path unless you have total knowledge of the maze. For the bidirectional stuff, basically you're searching for a path that connects the goal to any of the paths you can currently see, so you can prioritize starting at the end, or where you are now.

Comment: You are wrong, I do not have to see the whole just the parts that could offer a shorter path. As such A* requires a propper heuristic, i.e. hamilton distance for such a labyrinth. And the first path found will also be the shortest path there is. Take a closer look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm. What you can't do easily is to find the path with the least amount of steps. That's what I am looking for anyway.

Comment: I see, you're right about proving the shortest path if you can see all the parts that are around it.

Comment: _you can't really expect to find a shortest path_ a simple breadth first path search can find the shortest path without having  total knowledge of the maze. A* does so more efficiently.

Comment: @c0der You're missing the point. You can't do a breadth first search because it's a walking agent and the goal is to reduce the number of steps taken.

Comment: It would be fine to use BFS to find "a" solution but, in general, it will not use minimal steps. Maybe except that the lab is a single path but t.b.h. why should we bother about that case? DFS has a better chance to find the goal in minimal steps as it can be lucky in any lab to expand the minimal path first in that case the steps used by the agent would be minimal as well but that is very unlikely to happen.